# ReactJS deleting all information when starting to load the page

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a delete function using axios. my file looks like this

App.js

```
function App() {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


  const handleClick = (id) => {
    console.log("log!", + id); // when fetching in api all items are deleted when the page loads
   }


 return (
    <div className="App">
      { isLoading ?  'Loading...': <ListArticles posts={posts} handleClick={handleClick} /> }
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

ListArticles.js

```
function ListArticles(props) {
    const { posts, handleClick } = props;

    return (
         <div>

        { posts.map(post => (
            <div className="post" key={post.id}>
                
                <div className="btn">{ post.title}
                <button onClick={handleClick(post.id)}>Delete</button></div>
                
            </div>
        ))}
        
        
         </div>
    )
 }

 export default ListArticles;
```

everytime I loaded the page it automatically calls all handleClick, if I put the api calls here it deleted all the information on the database, which I don't want to. My target is every delete on once button only corresponse to. I'm only beginning to use react so please pardon the inconsistency of the code or the logic. Thank you

Comment: you probably want `<button onClick={() => handleClick(post.id)}>Delete</button></div>` to make your handler a lambda.

Comment: Hey! that works! Thank you @DCTID. I can now choose individual key :)